# Why is my returnurl getting $ (dollar signs) in from on the forward slash hashed code (%2F)?

Tags: php, excel, wordpress, hash, url-rewriting

I have a php function to autolog in users via SSO to wordpress.  It works fine but when users have a link in Excel or Word it redirects them to a login and then I need to return them via returnurl.

The link in Excel and Word spits out this for the returnurl

```
returnurl%3dhttps$%3A$%2F$%2Fsiteurl%2ecom$%2Fhome$%2Fcatalog$%2Ftransactional-connectivity$%2F
```

So the problem here is the `$%2F` should just be `%2F` for the forward slashes.  Well you notice that everything is prefixed with a "$" but the forward slash can't deal with it because it doesn't compute on redirect and knocks user back to the home page instead of the page they clicked on.

The part of the PHP code I wrote that handles this is in this function -

```
function safe_SSO() {
global $wpdb;
$wpprefix = $wpdb->prefix;
$url = 'https://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
session_set_cookie_params(60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
session_start();
define('SAFE_APP_ID', get_option('AppID'));
define('SAFE_KEY', get_option('AppKey'));
$safeurl = 'https://safe.siteurl.com/login/sso/SSOService?app=' . SAFE_APP_ID;
define('HOME', urlencode($url));
define('SAFE_REDIRECT', $safeurl . "&returnurl=" . urlencode($url));

if(is_user_logged_in()) {

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
}



else if(!is_user_logged_in()) {
// Start authentication and authorization
if (!isset($_SESSION['USER_ID']) && !isset($_POST['digest'])) {
// We've got no session and we've not returned from SAFE, so let's redirect to SAFE
header('Location: ' . SAFE_REDIRECT);
die();
}
if (!isset($_SESSION['USER_ID']) && isset($_POST['digest'])) {
// We've got no session but we've got a response from SAFE - let's check it
$safe_uid = $_POST['uid'];
$safe_name = $_POST['firstname'] . ' ' . $_POST['lastname'];
$safe_time = $_POST['time'];
$safe_email = $_POST['email'];
$safe_digest = $_POST['digest'];
$safe_returnurl = $_POST['returnurl'];
```

Comment: Either you SSO or the `Location` is automatically encoding the url so It's happening twice. Remove  `urlencode` in your script and try it again.

Comment: @bassxzero - That was it.  Unfortunately now I have a hash that looks correct but does not function when it is from Excel/Word.  The hash does work now if I copy/paste the URL.  Both returnurl's are the exact same.  Have you ran into SSO issues with return url from Excel/Word.  I know these two guys make you relogin... but the login process seems fine and spits out the same hash (exactly) but one works and one doesn't.

Comment: I haven't had any issues, but i did see something about it on the Shibboleth website once. I can't seem to find it now though. Sorry

Comment: If you are using Shibboleth the check this out https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/Tips+on+Integrating+Things#TipsonIntegratingThings-MicrosoftWordClickableLinks

Comment: Or this one https://admin.kuleuven.be/icts/services/aai/documentation/sp/linksfromofficetosp.html